# Process large amount of data using bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, bigdata

I've got to process a large amount of txt files in a folder using bash scripting.
Each file contains million of row and they are formatted like this:

File #1:

```
en ample_1 200
it example_3 24
ar example_5 500
fr.b example_4 570
fr.c example_2 39
en.n bample_6 10
```

File #2:

```
de example_3 4
uk.n example_5 50
de.n example_4 70
uk example_2 9
en ample_1 79
en.n bample_6 1
```

...

I've got to filter by "en" or "en.n", finding duplicate occurrences in the second column, sum third colum and get a sorted file like this:

```
en ample_1 279
en.n bample_6 11
```

Here my script:

```
#! /bin/bash
clear
BASEPATH=<base_path>
FILES=<folder_with_files>
TEMP_UNZIPPED="tmp"
FINAL_RES="pg-1"
#iterate each file in folder and apply grep
INDEX=0
DATE=$(date "+DATE: %d/%m/%y - TIME: %H:%M:%S")
echo "$DATE" > log
for i in ${BASEPATH}${FILES}
do
FILENAME="${i%.*}"
if [ $INDEX = 0 ]; then
  VAR=$(gunzip $i)
  #-e -> multiple condition; -w exact word; -r grep recursively; -h remove file path
  FILTER_EN=$(grep -e '^en.n\|^en ' $FILENAME > $FINAL_RES)
  INDEX=1
  #remove file to free space
  rm $FILENAME
else
  VAR=$(gunzip $i)
  FILTER_EN=$(grep -e '^en.n\|^en ' $FILENAME > $TEMP_UNZIPPED)
  cat $TEMP_UNZIPPED >> $FINAL_RES
  #AWK BLOCK
  #create array a indexed with page title and adding frequency parameter as value.
  #eg. a['ciao']=2 -> the second time I find "ciao", I sum previous value 2 with the new. This is why i use "+=" operator
  #for each element in array I print i=page_title and array content such as frequency
  PARSING=$(awk '{  page_title=$1" "$2;
                    frequency=$3;
                    array[page_title]+=frequency
                  }END{
                    for (i in array){
                      print i,array[i] | "sort -k2,2"
                    }
                  }' $FINAL_RES)

  echo "$PARSING" > $FINAL_RES
  #END AWK BLOCK
  rm $FILENAME
  rm $TEMP_UNZIPPED
fi
done
mv $FINAL_RES $BASEPATH/06/01/
DATE=$(date "+DATE: %d/%m/%y - TIME: %H:%M:%S")
echo "$DATE" >> log
```

Everything works, but it take a long long time to execute. Does anyone know how to get same result, with less time and less lines of code?

Comment: `bash` is *not* for processing *large* amount of data. If the data is big enough, it is worth spending your time on developing some more efficient program (probably in some compiled language). But *you* need to measure the balance and estimate the time. Waiting 5 minutes could be ok (but waiting 5 days for your bash script to finish justifies spending 2 hours on coding a C program, or an Ocaml one)

Comment: Also, how big is the actual data (megabytes or terabytes), how often does it change, and how long did you wait for your script to finish? And what are your programming skills?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UNIX shell is an environment from which to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to tools. The UNIX tool which shell calls to manipulate text is awk so just use it:

```
$ awk '$1~/^en(\.n)?$/{tot[$1" "$2]+=$3} END{for (key in tot) print key, tot[key]}' file | sort
en ample_1 279
en.n bample_6 11
```

Your script has too many issues to comment on which indicates you are a beginner at shell programming - get the books Bash Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson and Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ed. Yes, I'm new in shell programming. What issues are you talking about? I've got to handle lots of file in the same folder, it seems your script is able to process only one of this. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, there's literally far too many issues with your script for me to list them all. If you want the script to process more than one file just list the files on the command line, e.g `awk 'script' file1 file2 ... fileN` and obviously you can use `file*` or whatever construct you want the shell to expand to a list of file names

Comment: I think your regular expression is wrong, this suits my case well `$1~/^en$|^en.n/`. Thank you again!

Comment: You're right I accidentally had deleted a `?` during an edit, fixed now. The regexp you have in your comment is wrong as it will match, for example, lines that start with `enantiomer`.